# Check Solution of the following ODE: $\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}t} = - \frac{V}{RC} + \frac{I}{C}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

I am trying to solve the following differential equation

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}t} = - \frac{V}{RC} + \frac{I}{C}$$

where $V$ is a function of time.

Can you please check my solution:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{1}{R}\left(\frac{RI}{C}-\frac{V}{C}\right) $$

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\frac{RI-V}{C}} = \frac{1}{R}\mathrm{d}t$$

it is clear that $$ \frac{1}{RC}\mathrm{d}t = \frac{t}{RC}$$ in $[0,t]$

and $$ \int \frac{\mathrm{d}V}{RI-V} = -\log(RI-V) $$

therefore

$$ -\log(RI-V) = \frac{t}{RC}$$

equivalent

$$ \frac{1}{RI-V} = -e^{t/RC} $$

which yields

$$V = RI-e^{-t/RC} $$

but in my book the solution is

$$V = RI(1-e^{-t/RC})$$

Comment: you have an extra C on RHS here $\frac{dV}{\frac{RI-V}{C}} = \frac{1}{RC}dt$ and don't forget the constant of integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dV}{dt} = - \frac{V}{RC} + \frac{I}{C}$$
You had an extra $C$ in your attempts:
$$\frac{dV}{dt} = -\frac 1 {RC} \left ({V} - {RI}\right)$$
$$\frac{dV}{\left ({V} - {RI}\right)} = -\frac {dt} {RC} $$
Integrate and don't forget the constant of integration.
$$\ln{\left |{V} - {RI}\right|} = K-\frac {t} {RC} $$
$${\left |{V} - {RI}\right|} = Ke^{-\frac {t} {RC} }$$
$${V(t)} = {RI} + Ke^{-\frac {t} {RC} }$$
Maybe you have initial condition so that you can determine the value of the constant $K$ ? It seems that at $t=0$ you have $V(t)=0$ so that the constant $K=-RI$
$$\implies V(t)=RI(1-e^{-tR/C})$$

Comment: Thank you I have edited the question - in my book I get the solution $$ V = RI(1-e^{-t/RC})$$

Comment: ah i see its because of $-log()$

Comment: You're welcome @CB95 yes be carefull with the log function you have an absolute value

Comment: Do you habe any intital condition in your textbook ? @CB95

Comment: the initial condition is that V(t=0) = 0

Comment: Ah sure... then at t=0 V(0) = RI+K

Comment: I added some lines so now it looks correct and agrees with your book's answer @CB95

Comment: Dear @aryadeva many thanks :) perfect :)

Comment: You're welcome @CB95 ....